# Why is this $L^1$-sequence relatively weakly sequentially compact?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence, ergodic-theory

Let $(E,\mathcal E,m)$ be a probability space, $\theta$ be a measurable map on $(E,\mathcal E)$ with $m\circ\theta^{-1}=m$, $s_n$ be a real-valued nonpositive integrable random variable on $(E,\mathcal E,m)$ for $n\in\mathbb N$ with $\lambda:=\inf_{n\in\mathbb N}\int s_n\:{\rm d}m>-\infty$ and $$\varphi_n:=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n(s_i-s_{i-1}\circ\theta)\;\;\;\text{for }n\in\mathbb N.$$ It's easy to see that $$\int\varphi_n\:{\rm d}m=\frac{\int s_n\:{\rm d}m}n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\lambda\tag1.$$ Moreover, $$Tf:=f\circ\theta\;\;\;\text{for }f\in\mathcal L^1(m)$$ is a linear isometry on $L^p(m)$ for all $p\in[1,\infty]$. In particular, it is continuous with respect to the weak topology on $L^1(m)$.

> How can we show that, for all $i\in\mathbb N_0$ and $p\in\mathbb N$, there is an increasing $(n_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathbb N$ with $$\max\left(\varphi_{n_k}\circ\theta^i,-p\right)\xrightarrow{k\to\infty}\lambda_{i,\:p}\tag3$$ with respect to the weak topology on $L^1(m)$ for some $\lambda_{i,\:o}\in L^1(m)$? And how can we show that $\lambda_{i,\:p}$ is nondecreasing in $p$ almost surely?

These claims are made in the proof of Theorem 6.7 (in Chapter 4, Paragraph 6) of Revuz' *Markov Chains* book:
[image: proof of theorem 6.7]

I don't understand his arguments. For example, I guess he's talking about relative sequential compactness (I'm not sure, but may it be that this is equivalent to relative compactness in the weak topology?). It seems like he's using that $(\varphi_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is contained in a relatively sequentially compact set; but why is that the case? And why do the $\lambda_{i,\:p}$ need to satisfy the claimed monotonicity in $p$? Or does he mean that they can be chosen such that they satisfy this condition?

Comment: As far as I understand (2) is false in general. Do you perhaps have some additional conditions on $s_n$?

Comment: @JohnB I'm using the same assumptions and notation as in the book of Revuz. Here are the relevant 4 pages: https://docdro.id/AV3Jjg0.

Comment: I see, so $s_n$ is subadditive and so of course (1) holds. But I don't know what is $\sigma(L^1,L^\infty)$. What is it?

Comment: @JohnB It is the weak topology on $L^1$ (noting that by Riesz' representation theorem $(L^1)'\cong L^\infty$)

Comment: Doesn't make much sense, I doubt that this guy Revuz understood the proof. Anyways, we know that it comes from Kingman so my suggestion is that you go to the source, either Kingman or whoever this book refers to. Remember that Kingman depends on some compactness for the dual of $L^\infty$, that's why I say that it doesn't much sense.

Comment: @JohnB Actually, the book doesn't seem to refer to a particular reference. I'm not sure what kind of compactness you mean (and do you really mean the dual of $L^\infty$, which is $L^1$, or did you mean the dual of $L^1$, which is $L^\infty$?) Could you be more explicit.

Comment: I mean the dual of $L^\infty$, but in general this is not $L^1$. I suspect that you will profit from having a look at https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01013192

Comment: @JohnB Thank you for the reference; I'll take a look. Can you tell me why $\gamma$ (defined in definition 6.3) is called *time-constant*? I don't get the intuition behind this terminology.

Comment: It is foreign language to dynamics, the usual name would be time average (but the measure need not be ergodic). They also use the nonsense name "Markovian" for something that may have no relation to the Markov property.